# getter method does wait for a previous async call to complete

Tags: javascript, async-await, getter, alpine.js

I have this in my JS file :

```js
let xe = 0;

const get_usd2inr = async () =>
{
    return await fetch(BASE_URL + "api/usd")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response =>
    {
        return response;
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () =>
{
    xe = await get_usd2inr();
});

Alpine.store('local_data',
{
    // ...

    get ri_total()
    {
        let usd2inr = xe.usd2inr;
        let total = parseFloat(250 * usd2inr).toFixed(2);        
        const formatedNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { currency: 'INR' }).format(total);
        return formatedNumber;
    }
});
```

I have this in my HTML which probably gets called right after AlpineJS init and before DOMContentLoaded ?

```html
<input
    type="text" id="ri-total"
    :value="$store.local_data['ri_total']"
    x-mask-x:dynamic="$money($input)"
    readonly    
/>
```

The above INPUT's value is NaN when I want it a number, even if it's 0.

Comment: Add a default value to the line `let usd2inr = xe.usd2inr`, like `let usd2inr = xe.usd2inr || 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can default it to `0` via

```
return isNaN(formatedNumber) ? 0 : formatedNumber;
```

EDIT

If defaulting to another value, such as 20817 makes more sense, then you can use that as your default value instead of 0.

But relative currency values change over time, so it is up to you whether you have a better default than 0.

You will need to debug to see whether there are issues other than a lacking default, see what happens when you get valid values and if it defaults even then. Because if so, you might have a number formatting problem as well.

Comment: but in this case shouldnt it be 20,817 based on the 250 value in the method ?

Comment: @anjanesh it is up to you to choose the default that works for you best. If 20,817 is better for you, then use that. But this seems to be dollar-rupee conversion, so this value may change daily. Also, `,` inside a number tends to prevent you from converting a string containing the comma into a number, resulting in NaN. So please make sure that you thoroughly check what your values are and whether your conversions work well.

Comment: 250 is actually from a localStorage variable.

Comment: @anjanesh can you explain what the current problem is?

Comment: `get ri_total()` has `let total = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("cost") * usd2inr).toFixed(2);` which gets invoked on page load but is NaN because `get_usd2inr()` has not yet finished.